# ddrescue, range in multiples of bytes

Tags: ddrescue

When using ddrescue, is it possible to only specify the first 25Gio? I see that I can use the -i parameter with block sizes, but can this be specified with Gio directly?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Invoking-ddrescue) `-i` takes bytes. Then the manual states:

> Numbers given as arguments to options (positions, sizes, rates, etc) may be expressed as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal values (using the same syntax as integer constants in C++), and may be followed by a multiplier and an optional `B` for "byte". […]

There is a table which states `Gi` is a valid prefix for gibibyte, so `-i 25GiB` is valid.

But note `-i` is *not* what you want.

> ```
> -i bytes
> --input-position=bytes
> ```
>
> Starting position of the rescue domain in `infile`, in bytes. Defaults to `0`. […]

To only specify the first 25Gio, you should use `-s 25GiB` (and the default value of `-i`). This is what `-s` means:

> ```
> -s bytes
> --size=bytes
> ```
>
> Maximum size of the rescue domain in bytes. […]